# Unable to create temporary file in Java

Tags: java, file

I have a Java method that takes byte array and String value as arguments and returns a File object. This is the code

```
public File createTempFile(byte[] byteArray, String fileName) throws IOException {
    String prefix = FilenameUtils.getBaseName(fileName);
    String suffix = getMimeType(byteArray);
    File tempFile = File.createTempFile(prefix, suffix, null);
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    fos.write(byteArray);
    fos.close();
    return tempFile;
}
```

When I try to run it like this

```
File myFile = tiedostoService.createTempFile(tiedosto.getContent(), attachment.getFileName());
```

I get an IOException like this

```
java.io.IOException: Unable to create temporary file, C:\Users\ROSHAN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\kuva1068864619970584773image\png
at java.io.File$TempDirectory.generateFile(File.java:1921)
at java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:2010)
```

From the stacktrace. it can be seen that it's trying to create a file like `C:\Users\ROSHAN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\kuva1068864619970584773image\png`
and not `C:\Users\ROSHAN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\kuva1068864619970584773image.png`

How can I fix this? I'd really appreciate any sort of help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'image/png' is a Mime Type. See all MimeTypes in java [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19146-01/819-2630/abumi/index.html)

Write a util which converts mimetype to file extension. Hopefully this will help.

Comment: getMimeType(byteArray).substring(getMimeType(byteArray).lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
This line fixed it for me as it splits the last string from mimetype, which is used as extension. For example "png" from "image/png".

Answer (score 1):

I think there is an extra \ in your suffix string, could you try debug and see the actual value of the suffix?

I tried to run:

```
String suffix = "\\png";
```

and got the same error, but if I do

```
String suffix = ".png";
```

no error creating the temp file, notice that you need to add a dot in the suffix...

Comment: Turns out, I just needed to split the last string from suffix and in this case I simply used substring().lastindexof(). It worked like a charm after that.